# add class name in function.php child theme

Tags: php, function, woocommerce

how do I add a classname in function.php child theme.

I'm using this code to put the username inside the single product page, I can see the name but there is no classname into it, i have to put a classname so that I could customize it in css. how do I add a classname into it. I wanted the classname to be named "userabc".

```
function user_name() {
   global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo(); 
   echo $current_user->user_login ;

}

add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'user_name');
```

Comment: Which element will the class be applied to, in your code you are just echoing the user id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the class names then you need to either filter the [`body_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) or [`post_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class)

```
function user_name_class( $classes ) {
   $classes[] = get_current_user_id();
   return $classes;

}
add_action('post_class', 'user_name_class');
```